# Filter view by taxonomy terms of current user

Tags: views, 8

I've done lots of work with Drupal 6, but currently have no more ideas how to approach this problem in D8. Please help me :)

I have added taxonomy term field to user profile and would like to filter a view allowing only content having terms listed in user profile.

For example: User has terms "manager" and "south" is presented with content having either of this term without having to select exposed filters etc.

The point is not to restrict content (like with taxonomy access control), just to provide more relevant content.

Comment: I'm  interested by this issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same process as D7 (see [related thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69691/filter-user-in-views-based-on-taxonomy-contextual-filter))

But all you need to do is add a relationship to the taxonomy term and then add a contextual filter with the Term ID set as the fixed value.